# Múltiples formularios PHP

Tags: php, formularios

Tengo un formulario "A" con su respectivo PHP y JS todo bien, funciona. Si quiero agregar un nuevo formulario "B" en el mismo site ¿debo generar otro PHP y otro JS? ¿Cómo hago? ¿Si puedo utilizar los mismos archivos dónde inserto el código?

```js
$(function () {

    $('#contact-form').validator();

    $('#contact-form').on('submit', function (e) {
        if (!e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
            var url = "enviar_email.php";

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: url,
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function (data)
                {
                    var messageAlert = 'alert-' + data.type;
                    var messageText = data.message;

                    var alertBox = '<div class="alert ' + messageAlert + ' alert-dismissable"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>' + messageText + '</div>';
                    if (messageAlert && messageText) {
                        $('#contact-form').find('.messages').html(alertBox);
                        $('#contact-form')[0].reset();
                    }
                }
            });
            return false;
        }
    })
});
```

```html
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php'; 

    $from = new SendGrid\Email('name', "email@mail.com");
    $subject = "Nuevo requerimiento desde Khapac.com";
    $to = new SendGrid\Email('name', "email@mail.com");
    $categoria = strip_tags($_POST['categoria']);
    $detalles = strip_tags($_POST['detalles']);
    $email = strip_tags($_POST['email']);
    $nombre = strip_tags($_POST['nombre']);
    $telefono = strip_tags($_POST['telefono']);
    $content = new SendGrid\Content("text/html", "Hola, tienes un nuevo mensaje.<br><br>Categoría: $categoria<br>Detalles: $detalles<br>Email: $email<br>Nombre: $nombre<br>Teléfono: $telefono<br>");
    $mail = new SendGrid\Mail($from, $subject, $to, $content);
    $okMessage = "Hola $nombre, tu mensaje ha sido enviado.";
    $errorMessage = 'Se produjo un error, por favor inténtalo nuevamente.';
    $apiKey = 'MyApiKey';
    $sg = new \SendGrid($apiKey);
    $response = $sg->client->mail()->send()->post($mail);
    $status_code = $response->statusCode();
    if( substr($status_code,0,1) == 2 )
        $responseArray = array ('type' => 'success', 'message' => $okMessage, 'status'=> $status_code);
    else {
        $responseArray = array ('type' => 'danger', 'message' => $errorMessage, 'status' => $status_code);
    }

    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest')
    {   
    $encoded = json_encode($responseArray);
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo $encoded;
    }

    else {
    echo $responseArray['message'];
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 3):

No  necesitas otro JS pero sí otro PHP (en rigor se puede hacer con un solo PHP pero quedaría muy sucio). Suponiendo que tu nuevo formulario sea para dejar un comentario, y se envíe a `dejar_comentario.php`

Donde ahora tienes:

```
$(function () {

    $('#contact-form').validator();

    $('#contact-form').on('submit', function (e) {
        if (!e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
            var url = "enviar_email.php";
            ...
        }
    })
});
```

Quedaría como:

```
$(function () {

    $('#contact-form').validator();
    $('#contact-form2').validator();

    $('#contact-form').on('submit', function (e) {
        if (!e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
            var url = "enviar_email.php";
            ...
        }
    });

    $('#contact-form2').on('submit', function (e) {
        if (!e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
            var url = "dejar_comentario.php";
            ...
        }
    });
});
```

Obviamente reemplazando el endpoint y los ID donde corresponda

Comment: Excelente @amenadiel me funcionó.

Answer (score 1):

Si quieres usar el mismo php envía desde tu formulario un parámetro por ejemplo:

```
<!-- Formulario A -->
<form name="ejemplo1" action="POST">
     <input type="hidden" value="formA" name="parametro"/>
</form>
<!-- Formulario B -->
<form name="ejemplo2" action="POST">
     <input type="hidden" value="formB" name="parametro"/>
</form>
```

que php recibirá por POST y simplemente valides por ejemplo:

```
<?php
    // puedes validarlo como sea
    if ( isset( $_POST['parametro'] ) ) {
        if ( $_POST['parametro'] == 'formA' ) {
            // formulario A: hacer algo bonito
        } elseif ( $_POST['parametro'] == 'formB' ) {
            // formulario B: hacer algo genial
        }
    }
?>
```